# SSH script using pty and io.Copy to stream output with a menu

Tags: go, ssh, goroutine, pty

I have two issues that I need help with. I think I have it narrowed down to the use of io.Copy in the goroutine. It behaves like stdin needs to be "reactivated" with the enter key.

1. On the first iteration of the loop, everything works as expected. It logs into localhost, runs the command, the goroutine prints stdout and stderr. But on the subsequent iterations I must first press the enter key to "get out of the goroutine" then I can enter a response at the prompt. I suspect it has to do with os.Stdin. Could someone please offer some advise?
2. Can I send a sigterm to the ssh command without interrupting the script? For example, could I interrupt the ping output, and be dropped back at the menu prompt?

Thanks for any help you could provide. This is my first post on here.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

var (
    stdout, stderr io.Reader
    stdin          io.WriteCloser
    timeout        = 30 * time.Second
)

func sshConfig() *ssh.ClientConfig {
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: MYUSER,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(MYPASS),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.HostKeyCallback(func(hostname string, remote net.Addr, key ssh.PublicKey) error { return nil }),
        Timeout:         timeout,
    }
    return config
}

func options() {
  menuString := `
  Enter 1 for "uptime"
  Enter 2 for "ping -c 20 www.google.com"
  Type exit to exit
  `
    for i := 0; i <= 5; i++ {
        var num, cmd string
        fmt.Println(menuString)
        if i == 0 {
            fmt.Print("Select an option from above: ")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("You'll have to press enter before entering your option. Why?")
            fmt.Print("Select an option from above: ")
        }

        fmt.Scanln(&num)
        switch num {
        case "1":
            cmd = "uptime"
            connect(cmd)
        case "2":
            cmd = "ping -c 20 www.google.com"
            connect(cmd)
        case "exit":
            fmt.Println("exiting")
            os.Exit(0)
        default:
            fmt.Println("Invalid response")
            fmt.Println("Select an option from above: ")
        }
    }
}

func connect(c string) {
    config := sshConfig()
    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:22", config)
    defer conn.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dial target error:", err)
    }
    session, err := conn.NewSession()
    defer session.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("session failed:%v", err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
        ssh.ECHO:          0,     // disable echoing
        ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400, // input speed = 14.4kbaud
        ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400, // output speed = 14.4kbaud
    }
    err = session.RequestPty("xterm", 80, 40, modes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Pty request failed:%v", err)
    }

    stdin, err = session.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to setup stdin for session: %v", err)
    }
    stdout, err = session.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to setup stdout for session: %v", err)
    }
    stderr, err = session.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to setup stderr for session: %v", err)
    }

    quit := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-quit:
                fmt.Println("exiting goroutine")
                return
            default:
                fmt.Println("go routine is running")
                io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)
                io.Copy(stdin, os.Stdin)
                io.Copy(os.Stderr, stderr)
            }
        }
    }()

    if err := session.Run(c); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to run: " + err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("closing the channel")
    close(quit)
    fmt.Println("the channel is closed")
}

func main() {
    options()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, io.Copy is a blocking call that copies buffers of an io.writer to an io.reader until either EOF is reached on src or an error occurs. [Here's](https://golang.org/src/io/io.go?s=12980:13040#L357) a snippet from golang's io module:

```
// copyBuffer is the actual implementation of Copy and CopyBuffer.
// if buf is nil, one is allocated.

func copyBuffer(dst Writer, src Reader, buf []byte) (written int64, err error) {
    // If the reader has a WriteTo method, use it to do the copy.
    // Avoids an allocation and a copy.
    if wt, ok := src.(WriterTo); ok {
        return wt.WriteTo(dst)
    }
    // Similarly, if the writer has a ReadFrom method, use it to do the copy.
    if rt, ok := dst.(ReaderFrom); ok {
        return rt.ReadFrom(src)
    }
    if buf == nil {
        size := 32 * 1024
        if l, ok := src.(*LimitedReader); ok && int64(size) > l.N {
            if l.N < 1 {
                size = 1
            } else {
                size = int(l.N)
            }
        }
        buf = make([]byte, size)
    }
    for {
        nr, er := src.Read(buf)
        if nr > 0 {
            nw, ew := dst.Write(buf[0:nr])
            if nw > 0 {
                written += int64(nw)
            }
            if ew != nil {
                err = ew
                break
            }
            if nr != nw {
                err = ErrShortWrite
                break
            }
        }
        if er != nil {
            if er != EOF {
                err = er
            }
            break
        }
    }
    return written, err
}
```

Now to your questions
When the io.copy call is made on both stdin and stderr of the sessions in the first iteration, it waits till there's a message on both stderr and stdin to be copied and is blocked.
Simply replacing your goroutine to just do a copy stdout will give you the expected behavior on each iteration. Similarly stderr,stdin would required to be managed by their own goroutines:

```
go func() {
        for {
            io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)
        }
    }()
```

SigTerm would be used to terminate the session, there's a posix signal called interrupt that can be used to interrupt the cmd. [Here's](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Signal) a list os all POSIX signal the ssh library your using supports.

Here's a demo of the interrupt signal and expected behaviour:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

var (
    stdout, stderr io.Reader
    stdin          io.WriteCloser
    timeout        = 30 * time.Second
)

const (
    MYUSER = ""
    MYPASS = ""
)

func sshConfig() *ssh.ClientConfig {
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: MYUSER,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(MYPASS),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.HostKeyCallback(func(hostname string, remote net.Addr, key ssh.PublicKey) error { return nil }),
        Timeout:         timeout,
    }
    return config
}

func options() {
    menuString := `
  Enter 1 for "uptime"
  Enter 2 for "ping -c 20 www.google.com"
  Type exit to exit
  `
    for i := 0; i <= 5; i++ {
        var num, cmd string
        fmt.Println(menuString)
        if i == 0 {
            fmt.Print("Select an option from above: ")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("You'll have to press enter before entering your option. Why?")
            fmt.Print("Select an option from above: ")
        }

        fmt.Scanln(&num)
        switch num {
        case "1":
            cmd = "uptime"
            connect(cmd)
        case "2":
            cmd = "ping -c 20 www.google.com"
            connect(cmd)
        case "exit":
            fmt.Println("exiting")
            os.Exit(0)
        default:
            fmt.Println("Invalid response")
            fmt.Println("Select an option from above: ")
        }
    }
}

func connect(c string) {
    config := sshConfig()
    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:22", config)
    defer conn.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dial target error:", err)
    }
    session, err := conn.NewSession()
    defer session.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("session failed:%v", err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
        ssh.ECHO:          0,     // disable echoing
        ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400, // input speed = 14.4kbaud
        ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400, // output speed = 14.4kbaud
    }
    err = session.RequestPty("xterm", 80, 40, modes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Pty request failed:%v", err)
    }

    stdin, err = session.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to setup stdin for session: %v", err)
    }
    stdout, err = session.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to setup stdout for session: %v", err)
    }
    stderr, err = session.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to setup stderr for session: %v", err)
    }

    go func() {
        for {
            io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)
        }
    }()

    c = "echo 'go is awesome' && sleep 10 && " + c
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        session.Signal(ssh.SIGINT)
    }()

    if err := session.Run(c); err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to run: " + err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("closing the channel")
    fmt.Println("the channel is closed")
}

func main() {
    options()
}
```

Comment: Using this same example, is there a way I could send EOF into stdin without using a keystroke? For the times that I need to use stdin, avoid this behavior? I've tried using stdin.Write, os.Stdin.Write but I cannot get stdin to stop waiting.